# while creating a file with normal user it saying permission denyed..why?

Tags: redhat

I am new to RedHat 7. I am learning user management and file permission.
how to give permissions to normal user. So that he can create a file..

```
[syed1@localhost /]$ touch f1
touch: cannot touch ‘f1’: Permission denied
```

Comment: Don't create file at `/`.

Comment: please add some ls -l or other logs to help us understand what you are trying to do

Answer (score 3):

by default Normal user can create files under his home directory. So navigate to home directory of user with below command and create file.

```
# cd ~
# touch file1
```

if you want to create files outside home directory of user. Give sudo privileges to user.

Answer (score 0):

You must have sudo permissions applied to normal user or root user login to create file in root(/) of filesystem. Mostly we don't need to create files at / so I recommend to use your home directory to create a files using Below command.

```
touch ~/file1
```

> *where **~** symbol refers to your home directory*

If its really necessary to create a file in /, you can use sudo command below command to create a file.

```
sudo touch f1
```

---

If you have dont have sudo permissions to user, then you have to login with root user and execute below command to edit the sudoers file.

```
visudo
```

Then add below line to the file and save the file

```
myuser ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Now you can execute root privileged command using sudo before command.